# Read only a crop or extent of a raster in R

Tags: r, geospatial, raster, tiff, geotiff

I am working with a huge amount of data in daily tif files (thousands of daily files). I am analyzing the mean of the raster in a shapefile area, repeated over potentially thousands of shape layers.

My current .tif files are for an entire country when in reality I only need a small area of the of each tif file for each shapefile layer. Each shape layer has a different set of the days to extract from, i.e. data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(shplayer=c("shp_layerbuffer1","shp_layerbuffer2", "shp_layerbuffer3"), start=c("2000_02_18", "2004_03_19", "2010_08_20"), end=c("2010_01_09", "2005_03_15", "2012_09_04"))
```

Is there a way, in R, to crop a .tif (or any raster type file) BEFORE reading the file? This way I could read just the cropped area of each of the tif files

I envisoned something like (repeating across the entire set of dates):

```
library(sf)
library(raster)
shp_layerbuffer1 <- st_read("myshpfolder", layer="shp_layerbuffer1", quiet=T)

###EXAMPLE BUT doesn't work to crop the raster as it comes in
tempraster <- raster::raster("mytif_2000_02_18.tif", ext=extent(shp_layerbuffer1))
```

Then the usual velox (or raster) extract, repeat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're interested in the data rather than a raster object (or vrt/tiff), then this could be an approach:

If you "load" a raster from file, it doesn't necessarily mean that it gets loaded into memory, as the documentation of `raster` explains:

> In many cases, e.g. when a RasterLayer is created from a file, it does (initially) not contain any cell (pixel) values in (RAM) memory, it only has the parameters that describe the RasterLayer. You can access cell-values with getValues, extract and related functions. You can assign new values with setValues and with replacement.

So you could first "index" the raster and then use `getValuesBlock` to read the values which fall into your area of interest.

```
library(raster)

f <- system.file('external/test.grd',package = 'raster')

# index
r <- raster(f)

# check if in memory

inMemory(r)
#[1] FALSE # output

# this would be an extent from your overlapping shapefile
e <- extent(r,58,68,40,50)

# get cells from extent; either use cells as index directly or convert to rowcol

rowcol <- rowColFromCell(r,cellsFromExtent(r,e))

v <- getValuesBlock(r,row=rowcol[1,1],nrows=(rowcol[nrow(rowcol),1] - rowcol[1,1]),
                    col=rowcol[1,2],ncols=(rowcol[nrow(rowcol),2] - rowcol[1,2]))

v
# [1] 295.392 225.710 258.595 310.336 324.666 322.702 307.217 283.611 263.987 156.609 322.978 297.565 301.797 315.971
# [15] 323.605 326.920 317.894 297.138 270.027 225.769 337.503 323.388 314.900 308.877 314.556 343.555 344.035 315.400
# [29] 291.188 270.876 337.866 324.632 307.220 278.294 264.379 348.519 356.456 322.450 301.790 285.815 331.383 318.950
# [43] 299.246 262.026 230.869 294.012 320.274 312.777 300.513 285.317 321.075 311.447 296.952 278.519 270.279 283.797
# [57] 296.415 298.861 293.150 277.573 306.692 300.772 289.376 273.141 258.457 258.638 272.966 283.977 284.621 271.690
# [71] 286.749 286.617 275.618 247.307 198.884 193.865 240.465 268.687 277.303 271.431 260.336 271.458 263.977 231.071
# [85] 161.407 154.181 222.417 258.672 271.711 272.642 235.458 258.810 257.763 239.553 209.409 205.905 234.162 255.668
# [99] 266.260 270.532
```

#### EDIT:

```
# check if raster was loaded after getValuesBlock
inMemory(r)
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: @loki No I don't believe so. Calling `raster` doesn't load the data, just metadata. Only `getValues` or the like will load data into memory ... this is where the subset comes in.

Comment: No worries ... Personally I really like `vrt` ... could be just a bit overkill for this purpose - but really comes down to personal taste IMO :)

Comment: You are absolutely right. I learned to love vrts and use them quite a lot lately

Comment: I'm not sure vrts are any faster than reading straight tifs into velox, at least for my purposes of raster extraction. See my tests here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50870080/fastest-way-to-extract-a-raster-in-r-improve-the-time-of-my-reproducible-code

Comment: @NealBarsch Your original question was how to partially read files (aka crop extents) into memory. Both solutions answered it, and if you liked loki 's answer, I don't see a reason un-accepting it. The performance aspect seems to be covered in your subsequent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50870080/fastest-way-to-extract-a-raster-in-r-improve-the-time-of-my-reproducible-code)

Comment: I was mostly trying to stimulate some more debate on what is fastest :)

Answer (score 5):

In such a case, I would create a [**virtual raster file** (VRT)](http://gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html) with the `gdalUtils` package. It is the quickest way to create a subset (or even virtual mosaic) of one or multiple raster data sets. For this VRT you can set the **desired extent** using the `sf::st_bbox`.

Minimal (not reproducible) example would be:

```
library(gdalUitls)
library(raster)
library(sf)

shp_layerbuffer1 <- st_read("myshpfolder", layer="shp_layerbuffer1", quiet=T)

gdalbuildvrt(gdalfile = "yourraster.tif", 
             output.vrt = "tmp.vrt", 
             te = st_bbox(shp_layerbuffer1))

tempraster <- raster("tmp.vrt")
```

The VRT basically creates a virtual canvas for a new "raster" file. It then references the corresponding rows and columns from the (one or multiple) underlying raster file(s). Hence, you **do not** need to create a whole new raster but simply reference existing files. The file size of your VRT should not exceed some kBytes.

Comment: Hi Loki, Thanks so much for this! I keep getting ```Error in paste(parameter_values[[which(names(parameter_values) == X)]],  : 
  non-string argument to internal 'paste'``` any ideas why?

Comment: So check this out: if you crop once in raster it goes way faster, but not on the file load. Also thanks for your work on this!

Comment: ```test7 <- system.time(mclapply(seq_along(x1), function(x){ ras<-velox("testras_so.tif");ras$crop(poly);ras$extract(poly, fun=function(t) mean(t,na.rm=T)) }))

test8 <- system.time(mclapply(seq_along(x1), function(x){ ras<-velox("testras_so.tif");ras$crop(st_buffer(st_sfc(st_point(c(x1[x],y1[x]), dim="XY"),crs=32651),200000));ras$extract(poly, fun=function(t) mean(t,na.rm=T)) }))

> test7
   user  system elapsed 
  0.011   0.016   4.450 
> test8
   user  system elapsed 
  0.006   0.012   4.333 ```